# The horizontal scroll bar & blank space coming in the HTML

Tags: html, css

I want you to help me with the "horizontal scroll bar" coming in the HTML. I don't want it but it is unnecessarily coming please debug my code and please tell me the problem that is with this code.
My code is here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2KfV.png):-
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16Uocf15o0XBovswjvGvLf3CRRwyIze7P?usp=sharing

Regards,
Hridyansh Sati

Comment: Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Add your code here

Answer (score 0):

In your css file you use `translate` to center a heading which is wrong practice.
Assuming that your heading is in a `div`, you can center it with `text-align:center;`
If you want to vertically align it, you will need to use Flexbox or Grid.
To solve your problem, change your `.sec2` css class to this:

```
.sec2{
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

As stated, you **must add your code in your question**.

Comment: Thanks, George Bro. Next time, I will use the "text-align" property in place of the "translate" property. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some CSS into your stylesheet I hope it will work.

```
body{
     overflow-y: scroll;
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. `overflow-x: hidden;` won't help you debug which element is causing you problems and ultimately fix that. It will just hide any mess, which is not optimal. Also, `overflow-y: scroll;` is the default setting for most, if not all, browsers - so unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, Alam Bro. It helped me.

Comment: This code work to fix the problem. I take to so small time to fix the issue. @GeorgeChond Got it.